# To Select a set of lines and save it to another file in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

i want select a set of lines start with set of characters and end with another set of characters and save it to another file.

the regular expression am using

```
create or replace procedure.*?/
```

my file contains

```
create or replace procedure proc1 IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('running proc1');
   RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
END;
/

create table emp(one varchar2(20),two varchar2(20));


create or replace procedure delete_dept(f_emp_id dept.emp_id%type) is
begin
  delete from dept where emp_id=f_emp_id;
  if sql%notfound then
     raise_application_error(-20050,'Cannot Delete The Invalid ID');
  end if;
  COMMIT;
end delete_dept;
/

alter table emp modify emp one varchar2(30);
```

i tried option in Find ->Mark  but when i copy the Bookmarked line i only get the first line like this

```
create or replace procedure proc1 IS
create or replace procedure delete_dept(f_emp_id dept.emp_id%type) is
```

Comment: That's not possible using bookmarks as you can only bookmark the first line of a match selection (as you have noted). I'm not aware of an easy workaround other than inverting the selection - deleting the inverted selection - copying what is left - undoing the delete - paste into the other file.

Answer (score 2):

1. go to "search" menu > find > "mark" tab
2. find what :  create or replace .*
3. check the box against "bookmark line"  and select "regular expression" radio button
4. click "mark all"

Total 2 lines were bookmarked.

5. now go to "search" menu > bookmark > copy bookmarked line.

Following lines were copied successfully:

.*create or replace procedure proc1 IS*

.*create or replace procedure delete_dept(f_emp_id dept.emp_id%type) is*

Comment: i need the whole procedure body